# How can i check what the coordinates of a specific object on my map is?

Tags: c#

So i'm trying to make a battleship game. To start off i just want to be able to place ships at specific locations, they don't need to be longer then 1 space yet. But i'm having trouble understanding how to check what the location of an object in my ship array is.

What i want to do is be able to put in a location, for example 3,3 and check to see if there is a ship there. Of course there is more stuff that i will add after like bigger ships, playing against the PC who can place the ships at random locations preferably. But for now it's just this thing i can't seem to figure out.

I'm pretty much new to programming so if you see anything questionable about this script feel free to point it out.

My main class where i initialize the ship array and the board.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Board board = new Board(10, 10);

        try
        {

            Ship[] ships =
            {
                new Ship(new BoardLocation(1, 3, board)),
                new Ship(new BoardLocation(3, 5, board)),
                new Ship(new BoardLocation(5, 7, board))

            };

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the coordinate: ");
            double cr1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (cr1 == ships.Contains<>)
            {

            }
```

My board class:

```
namespace Battleship
{
class Board
{
    public readonly int Width;
    public readonly int Height;

    public Board(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;

    }

    public bool OnBoard(Point point)
    {
        return point.X >= 0 && point.X < Width &&
               point.Y >= 0 && point.Y < Height;
    }

    }
}
}
```

My boardlocation class:

```
namespace Battleship
{
class BoardLocation : Point
{
    public BoardLocation(int x, int y, Board board) : base(x, y)
    {
        if (!board.OnBoard(this))
        {
            throw new OutOfBoundsException(x + "," + y + " is outside the 
            boundaries of the map.");
        }

    }
}
}
```

My ship class:

```
namespace Battleship
{
class Ship
{
    public readonly int shipHealth = 1;
    public readonly double shipLocation;

    public BoardLocation _location;

    public Ship(BoardLocation location)
    {
        _location = location;
    }     


}
}
```

Comment: You could just loop over your ships and check to see if any is at the specified coordinates. Although it's possible there is a better long-term solution.

Comment: Okay but how do i check the specific coordinates of a single ship obect? That was kinda what i meant with my question, I'm not sure how to do that. How can i check inside my array if there are any ship objects at x location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the `FirstOrDefault` method. This will return `null` if the criteria does not match and if it does it will return the item. So after reading both coordinates:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the X coordinate: ");
int X_input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter the Y coordinate: ");
int Y_input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

To check the coordinates you need to access the `X` and `Y` properties of the `_location`. You can do it using linq

```
Ship mayBeHit = ships.FirstOrDefault(
                ship => ship._location.X==X_input && 
                ship._location.Y == Y_input);
```

then you can check whether you have a **hit**

```
if(maybeHit != null)
{
    // use the ship the you hit
}
```

Comment: Yep. That would work. Slightly better for his purpose would be `Any()`, since he doesn't want to actually fetch the ship that holds the position.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what i was looking for. I haven't been learning about linq yet. Thanks alot!

Comment: @dotNET I can imagine that he actually wants the `Ship` because after a hit it has to be destroyed. So having it would be in this case an advantage

Comment: @JesseSchoonveld You are welcome. Why did you make the `public readonly int shipHealth = 1;` readonly? Don't you want to destroy the `Ship` when it got hit? I guess you would set the health to `0`, or how did you plan to do it?

Comment: Oh yes you are right, i had not really thought about that to be honest. I'm not sure why i did that, might have something to do with me trying to code when i was very tired haha. But thanks for pointing it out.